# how to add a rectangle after a certain period in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am wondering how I could add a rectangle shape after the user has gained 10 points.

I have a function called blocks() which simply draws a rectangle. The code snippet that I have written for this is

```
#bunch of code
main_gameloop()

 while running:
      #bunch of code

       if score >= 10:
          blocks()
          pygame.display.update()
       p.display.update()
       clock.tick(fps)
main_gameloop()
```

But what happens is that when the user has gained 10p the rectangle just flashes on and off it doesnt display as a solid

Comment: Could you please add the `blocks()` code that is pertinent to drawing the rectangle as that can help with fixing the issue.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill the blocks() code is simply just pygame.draw.rect(screen, color,  x1,y1,x2,y2)

Comment: dont call display.update twice, only once per loop

Answer (score 1):

> when the user has gained 10p the rectangle just flashes on and off
>
> > it doesnt display as a solid

I am presuming that this logic is stepped through each time clock.tick runs.  The flickering is caused by the rectangle re-drawing itself each time "blocks()" is called as per your timer.

You could prevent the rectangle from flickering by checking to see if the rectangle has already been drawn before re-drawing it.

Some pseudo code is provided below

```
    bool shown = false

    blocks() 
       …
       shown=true

    if score >= 10 
       if ! shown 
          blocks()
       …
       clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: you are completely right about blocks() being called per the timer this is because when the game is starting their is one rectangle moving from right to left which the user needs to dodge. My problem is that I want another rectangle to move in the same way but when the score is 10 or higher

Comment: never mind I solved it, I was drawing it  before my screen.fill()